# SQL Server : create new column that is subtraction of date column from today's date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, subtraction

UPDATED

Based on responses to my original question I adjusted my code to the following:

```
SELECT 
    [OPCODE], [dtbuilt],
    [EVENT_2], 
    [AGE_NO_DAYS] = DATEDIFF(day, - dtbuilt, CAST(GETDATE() As DATE)) 
INTO #df_EVENT5_6 
FROM #df_EVENT5_5
```

Below is the error I'm receiving:

> Operand data type datetime is invalid for minus operator

Values in dtbuilt column are as follows: `1999-11-29 00:00:00.000`

I want to create a new column in SQL Server called `AGE_NO_DAYS` that is today's date minus a datetime column called `dtbuilt`.

Below is the code I tried but it errors out.

```
SELECT 
    [OPCODE], [dtbuilt],
    [AGE_NO_DAYS] = CAST(GETDATE() As DATE) - [dtbulit]    
INTO
    #df_EVENT5_6 
FROM 
    #df_EVENT5_5
```

This is the error I get:

> Invalid column name 'dtbulit'.

Comment: Can you show us the table definition of table #df_events_5?

Comment: how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misspelling in your code and you should be using `dateadd()`.  Try:

```
SELECT [OPCODE], 
       [dtbuilt],
       [AGE_NO_DAYS] = DATEDIFF(day, dtbuilt, CAST(GETDATE() As DATE))    
INTO #df_EVENT5_6 
FROM #df_EVENT5_5
```

Note that you could do this with a computed column:

```
alter table #df_EVENTS_5 add age_num_days as (DATEDIFF(day, dtbuilt, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE));
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error when I run your suggested code: Operand data type datetime is invalid for minus operator

Comment: @PineNuts0 . . . That's why I had switched the code to `dateadd()`.

Comment: I am using DATEADD as you suggested ... but the error is the one I mentioned above

Comment: @PineNuts0 . . . Oh, you want `datediff()` instead.

Comment: ah, it's working now!  I removed the - from dtbuilt ... thank you so much :)